# POST to a related collection in WEB API 2 with OData 4

Tags: odata, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-web-api-odata

I want to have a route like:

```
/Accounts(id)/Orders
```

where I can execute a POST to create an order. I can't find a way to add this route using OData in WebApi. For GET there is a convention to follow to get related collections, but I am not able to find any convention for posting new entities to a related collection.

Is there a standard way to handle this POST request with Web API 2 and OData 4 ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Added the following attributes to the method and it worked:

```
[HttpPost]
[ODataRoute("Accounts({key})/Orders")]
public IHttpActionResult Orders([FromODataUri] string key, OrderDto orderDto)
{

}
```