# How to post to a related collection in odata webapi

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, odata, asp.net-web-api2

I've found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27506627/post-to-a-related-collection-in-web-api-2-with-odata-4) which helped me to set a route, but I'm having a problem adding entity to a related collection.

Models:

```
public class Book
{
    public int BookId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; } and so on

    [ForeignKey("AuthorId")]
    public ICollection<Author> Authors { get; set; }
}

public class Author
{
    public int AuthorId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("BookId")] 
    public ICollection<Book> Books { get; set; }
}
```

Controller method for posting to a related collection:

```
    [ODataRoute("Books({key})/Authors")]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> PostAuthor([FromODataUri] int key, Author author)
    {
        var book = await db.Books.FindAsync(key);
        if (book == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
        book.Authors.Add(author);

        await db.SaveChangesAsync();
        return StatusCode(HttpStatusCode.NoContent);
    }
```

I can see that Author is sent through, but book.Authors is null and you can't add to it.
[link to image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5WqdL.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find won't bring back children. Try:

```
var book = await db.Books
                    .Include(b => b.Authors)
                    .FirstOrDefaultAsync(b => b.BookId == key);
```

[Load related entities](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Comment: Yes, sorry had a typo - you don't need a Where() when using FirstOrDefault.

Comment: I edited your answer with my sollution so that I can accept it. Your anwer was the closest to answering it, but it gave an error in VS.